# Execute javascript inside vue component template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In a vue.js component I'm trying to compile a variable in a template but its not getting compiled/converted. Any advice how I can achieve the following:

```
<template>
    <img src="{{ window.SETTINGS.ASSETS_DIR + 'img/foo.jpg' }}"/>
</template>
```

Where settings is:

```
window.SETTINGS = {
  ASSETS_PATH: '/wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/',
  API_BASE_PATH: '/wp-json/wp/v2/'
}
```

Comment: `<img v-bind:src="window.SETTINGS.ASSETS_DIR + 'img/foo.jpg'"/>` use v-bind for attributes

Comment: You can use [lodash templating](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#template) to compile a string and do interpolation.

Comment: Your `windows.SETTINGS` object doesn't contain a variable called `ASSETS_DIR`.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because Vue doesn't know anything about `window.SETTINGS`.

You should reference `window.SETTINGS` to property in `data` object, in your Vue Component/Instance.

```
data() {
  return {
    settings: window.SETTINGS
  }
}
```

Other option could be to extend `Vue.prototype` If you need this over the whole app:

```
Vue.prototype.SETTINGS = {
  ASSETS_PATH: '/wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/',
  API_BASE_PATH: '/wp-json/wp/v2/'
}
```

And then you can access It everywhere by typing:

```
this.SETTINGS
```

And last step would be to not use the interpolation, but instead go with the binding:

```
<img :src="SETTINGS.ASSETS_PATH + 'hello.jpg'" alt="">
```